# Selecting correct placement programmatically

Tags: jquery

I have two groups of elements:

```js
$('div').on('click', function() {
  $('#h2').after(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="h1">header 1</h2>
<div id="item45" data-time="07:00">item45</div>
<div id="item12" data-time="09:00">item12</div>
<div id="item33" data-time="14:30">item33</div>
<div id="item43" data-time="19:00">item43</div>

<h2 id="h2">header 2</h2>
<div id="item7" data-time="09:00">item7</div>
<div id="item13" data-time="14:00">item13</div>
<div id="item22" data-time="17:30">item22</div>
<div id="item35" data-time="22:00">item35</div>
```

I need to move an element from the first group under ***header 1*** to the second group under ***header 2*** with jQuery.

It isn't difficult just to move, but the item has to fit into a chronological order, based on data-time attribute.

For example, if I move #item33 it will have to be placed between #item13 and #item22. Not sure how I'd do that programmatically:

```
$('#item33').after('#item13);
```

Also, what if I was moving #item45, it'll have to be .before('#item7').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use `nextAll()` along with `filter()` to figure out insertion point

```
var $item = $('#item33'),
    itemTime = $('#item33').data('time')
var $nextList = $('#h2').nextAll();

// filter items based on time being greater 
$nextList.filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('time') >= itemTime;
 // insert before the first one
}).first().before($item);
```

Would need some additional logic if none are greater or equal to the one being moved

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2p391jdf/)**</kbd>

Comment: This is great! I guess I can check if there any other items under #h2 before running the function?

Comment: Would be best to use some container elements